# What is difference between Spring interceptor and AOP?

Tags: spring, aop, interceptor

It's seems both looking same. Interceptor are like filter and even AOP(Aspect Oriented Programming in Spring) also will work as filter. My doubt what's difference between them.

Answer (score 4):

**Spring Interceptors**

> Spring Interceptors has the ability to pre-handle and post-handle the
>   web requests. Each interceptor class should extend the
>   HandlerInterceptorAdapter class

**Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP)**

> Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP) complements Object-Oriented
>   Programming (OOP) by providing another way of thinking about program
>   structure. The key unit of modularity in OOP is the class, whereas in
>   AOP the unit of modularity is the aspect.
>
> Aspects enable the modularization of concerns such as transaction
>   management that cut across multiple types and objects. (Such concerns
>   are often termed crosscutting concerns in AOP literature.).AOP aspects are a complex subject

Comment: Thanks...got it. Is there any good sites to discuss more details ?

Comment: Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP): https://docs.jboss.org/aop/1.0/aspect-framework/userguide/en/html/what.html https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Comment: Spring Interceptor:[link] https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-interceptor.html

Comment: @Anil Nivargi I hope this is use full

Comment: Thanks vignesh...it's helpfull